# Remove characters after the @ in and email address - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I would like to remove the characters and the @ symbol from an email address to create a username. So **somethinghere@email.com** would become **somethinghere** can anyone shed some light on how to do this please? I have googled it and cant seem to find much on the subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.Net?

Comment: You can use `Substring` and `IndexOf`. But, if you mean username which should be unique, what about `somethinghere@gmail.com` and `somethinghere@yahoo.com`?

Comment: @Epsilon : ah i didn't see your comment

Comment: @thatuxguy : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: Samiey Mehdi's example worked perfectly. Basically i just wanna get a suggested username from a users email address. If they choose (or its already taken) that would be down to their own choice. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string s = "somethinghere@email.com"; 
string username = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('@'));
Response.Write(username);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code, which is very simple,

```
string email="somethinghere@email.com";
int indexOfAt=email.IndexOf("@");
int lenOfEmail=email.Length;
string result=email.Substring(0,indexOfAt);
```